# Code is not displaying Grayscale image using android ndk

Tags: opencv, android-ndk, java-native-interface

My code is not displaying the image as grayscale , as I am using android ndk in eclipse

`jni part :`

Below part for brightness work for me

```
   jint* _in = env->GetIntArrayElements(in, 0);
   jint* _out = env->GetIntArrayElements(out, 0);

   Mat mSrc(height, width, CV_8UC4, (unsigned char*)_in);
   Mat bgra(height, width, CV_8UC4, (unsigned char*)_out);
   vector<Mat> sChannels;
   split(mSrc, sChannels);

        for(int i=0; i<sChannels.size(); i++)
        {
            Mat channel = sChannels[i];
            equalizeHist(channel, channel);
        }
        merge(sChannels, bgra);
   env->ReleaseIntArrayElements(in, _in, 0);
   env->ReleaseIntArrayElements(out, _out, 0);

   jint retVal;
   int ret = 1;
   retVal = jint(retVal);
   return retVal;
```

But when i change the same above code for converting the image into grayscale its not showing output

```
       jint* _in = env->GetIntArrayElements(in, 0);
       jint* _out = env->GetIntArrayElements(out, 0);

       Mat mSrc(height, width, CV_8UC4, (unsigned char*)_in);
       Mat bgra(height, width, CV_8UC4, (unsigned char*)_out);
       cvtColor(mSrc , bgra , CV_BGRA2GRAY);
       env->ReleaseIntArrayElements(in, _in, 0);
       env->ReleaseIntArrayElements(out, _out, 0);

       jint retVal;
       int ret = 1;
       retVal = jint(retVal);
       return retVal;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CV_BGRA2GRAY` expects the output to be **CV_8UC1**. To generate BGRA output, you can use a temporary image and 2 conversions:

```
   Mat mSrc(height, width, CV_8UC4, (unsigned char*)_in);
   Mat gray(height, width, CV_8UC1);
   Mat bgra(height, width, CV_8UC4, (unsigned char*)_out);
   cvtColor(mSrc , gray , CV_BGRA2GRAY);
   cvtColor(gray , bgra , CV_GRAY2BGRA);
```

Comment: @Alex Cohn But I want output as gray scale image , when I use it as `CV_8UC1` , it display 4 images on android device

Comment: when use 2 conversion it give me back the rgba image isn't ?

Comment: I don't know how you display your bitmap; it's quite possible in Java to handle a 8bpp `gray` bitmap. But usually we wrap 32-bot-per-pixel image in Android native bitmap. For this, I use the second conversion. No, it will not give back the RGBA image because the second conversion uses only grayscale information from the `gray` Mat. It will be properly expanded from 8bpp to 32 bpp by OpenCV.

Comment: @AlexCohn but is it different for every case ? like if we remove both line of `cvtColor` from above code and replace it with `bilateralFilter(mSrc, bgra, 5, 5, 50);` then it shows no result too , even it work for me on visual studio , why is that , and is it different for every case ? Thanks

Comment: I am not sure I understand your follow-up question, but note that any image manipulation is followed by Java part that displays the result. This second step should be tuned to accept correctly the result of the first, OpenCV, step.

Comment: Specifically [doc for `bilateralFilter()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/filtering.html?highlight=bilateralfilter#bilateralfilter) says that it works for 1 or 3-channel images; **mSrc** and **bgra** have 4 channels.

Comment: +1 ,**mSrc** and **bgra** are 4 channels , Yes because Java accept 4 channels (in bitmap) isn't ? so how can I work it with 8UC3 ? though i apply `Mat mSrc(height, width, CV_8UC3, (unsigned char*)_in);` and `Mat mSrc(height, width, CV_8UC3, (unsigned char*)_in);` it and show me output , but is it possible that i apply all the function in jni using `8UC3` or do i need to make 2 seprate `in` and `out` of 8UC4 and 8UC3 , because if i use 8UC3 for all function then its not showing output of grayscale , thank you

Comment: @AlexCohn Can you please help me here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25466319/result-showing-lining-on-image