# Result showing lining on image

Tags: java, opencv, android-ndk, java-native-interface, computer-vision

I am using opencv with android ndk , Below is my jni code:

```
void Vignete(Mat& img1, Mat& img2, Mat& out)
{

    resize(img1, img1, img2.size());
    img1.convertTo(img1,CV_32FC4,1.0/255.0);
    img2.convertTo(img2, CV_32FC4, 1.0/255.0);
    vector<Mat> ch;
    Mat I1;
    split(img2,ch);
    Mat alpha1 = ch[3];
    Mat alpha = alpha1.clone();
    Mat ch0 = ch[0];
    Mat ch1 = ch[1];
    Mat ch_2 = ch[2];
    Mat ch_3 = ch[3];
    cv::multiply(alpha,ch0,ch0);
    cv::multiply(alpha,ch1,ch1);
    cv::multiply(alpha,ch_2,ch_2);
    cv::multiply(alpha,ch_3,ch_3);
    vector<Mat> newVec;
    newVec.push_back(ch0);
    newVec.push_back(ch1);
    newVec.push_back(ch_2);
    newVec.push_back(ch_3);
    merge(newVec, I1);
    vector<Mat> ch2;
    Mat I2;
    split(img2,ch2);
    Mat ch_0 = ch2[0];
    Mat ch_1 = ch2[1];
    Mat ch_21 = ch2[2];
    Mat ch_31 = ch2[3];
    cv::multiply(1.0-alpha,ch_0,ch_0);
    cv::multiply(1.0-alpha,ch_1,ch_1);
    cv::multiply(1.0-alpha,ch_21,ch_21);
    cv::multiply(1.0-alpha,ch_31,ch_31);
    vector<Mat> newVec1;
    newVec1.push_back(ch_0);
    newVec1.push_back(ch_1);
    newVec1.push_back(ch_21);
    newVec1.push_back(ch_31);
    merge(newVec1, I2);
    Mat result = I1+I2;
    result.convertTo(out, CV_8UC4, 255);
    }
```

Below is my jni calling method :

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_org_opencv_samples_NativeActivity_CvNativeActivity_Vig(
        JNIEnv* env, jobject, jint width, jint height, jint i, jint j, jintArray in,jintArray inn,
        jintArray out) {
    jint* _in = env->GetIntArrayElements(in, 0);
    jint* _inn = env->GetIntArrayElements(inn, 0);
    jint* _out = env->GetIntArrayElements(out, 0);

    Mat mSrc(height, width, CV_8UC4, (unsigned char*) _in);
    Mat nSrc(i, j, CV_8UC4, (unsigned char*) _inn);
    Mat bgra(height, width, CV_8UC4, (unsigned char*) _out);
    Vite(mSrc,nSrc, bgra);
    jint retVal;
    int ret = 1;
    retVal = jint(retVal);
    return retVal;
    }
```

Result :

[image]

`My java calling` , where img1 is `image in snapshot` and img2 `image 2 is vignette of 4 channel` is input and out is output

```
InputStream is , Vign;
is = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.me);
final Bitmap bmInImg = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
Vign = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.drawable.vig2);
final Bitmap bmInImg2 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(Vign);

mPhotoIntArray = new int[bmInImg.getWidth() * bmInImg.getHeight()];
nPhotoIntArray = new int[bmInImg.getWidth() * bmInImg.getHeight()];
vPhotoIntArray = new int[bmInImg2.getWidth() * bmInImg2.getHeight()];
imageview_1.setImageBitmap(bmInImg);

bmInImg.getPixels(mPhotoIntArray, 0, bmInImg.getWidth(), 0, 0, bmInImg.getWidth(), bmInImg.getHeight());
bmInImg2.getPixels(vPhotoIntArray, 0, bmInImg2.getWidth(), 0, 0, bmInImg2.getWidth(), bmInImg2.getHeight());

mCannyOutArray = new int[bmInImg.getWidth() * bmInImg.getHeight()];
final Bitmap bmOutImg = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmInImg.getWidth(), bmInImg.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);  
bmOutImg.setPixels(mCannyOutArray, 0, bmInImg.getWidth(), 0, 0, bmInImg.getWidth(), bmInImg.getHeight());

Vig(bmInImg.getHeight(),bmInImg.getWidth(),bmInImg2.getHeight(),bmInImg2.getWidth(), mPhotoIntArray,vPhotoIntArray, mCannyOutArray); 
Bitmap bmOutImg = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmInImg.getWidth(), bmInImg.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);  
bmOutImg.setPixels(mCannyOutArray, 0, bmInImg.getWidth(), 0, 0, bmInImg.getWidth(), bmInImg.getHeight());   
imageview_2.setImageBitmap(bmOutImg);
```

Img1:

[image]

img2 :

[image]

I am working on native environment using eclipse with opencv android version of 2.4.8.

Comment: "The other way I am trying in which i am getting error on resize and merging" What is the error?

Comment: I don't think you have 5 channels in img1, so Mat mask = ch[4].clone();  sould be Mat mask = ch[3].clone(); And why do you blend alpha channels when blend images?

Comment: @AndreySmorodov I am using the same approach as here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23801988/merging-two-images-showing-brightness  but i am using it with java and android ndk , as i also updated my question

Comment: You resized ch to 3, but in multiply you reference to ch[3], which is 4-th channel.

Comment: I changed it but still to affect

Comment: Can you build ndk module? Or there are compile time errors?

Comment: Instead clone, you can create image, then use copyTo method. Instead multiply, you can try use mul metod of matrix ( Img1.mul(Img2) ).

Comment: `split(Img1,ch);` won't compile - should be `split(img1,ch);`
Also, please show your include files, and relevant declarations (if any)

Comment: @AndreySmorodov I have 3 arguments in multiply regarding channels as well , how i can use the full image with `mul` ?

Comment: I1=I0.mul(I2) for example. http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat-mul

Comment: Your code compiles fine for me - no unresolved clone etc. can you get any OpenCV code working? Perhaps your install is broken.

Comment: did you check on android ndk ? it work for mee too on visual studio , my opencv is working fine as i have many others opencv function is working there too

Comment: I update my java code as well

Comment: what are you trying to do? Maybe there's a better way to do it and it doesn't result in this kind of bugs. Also, did you release those arrays? It's very essential to release data.

Comment: I am trying to do some sort of this thing with android ndk http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23801988/merging-two-images-showing-brightness , i explained everything in question

Comment: @Froyo Yes am releasing arrays , above is all my code and am using `env->ReleaseIntArrayElements(out, _out, 0);` , what are the other way ? can you answer that way

Comment: I think nothing is wrong with your definition of function `vite()` in first attempt , it look to me that something is wrong in java calling or jni calling , you can simply do the first part as `cv::resize(img2,img2,img1.size());
    out=img1+img2;`

Comment: @Ahmad I edit it and remove the 2nd way which is of no use , Thanks

Comment: You still don't provide the exact "error on resize and multiply". If it is a compile error, how do you get the output image?

Comment: @B... I am getting error on them that why I didn't use them , because its not compiling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if your both images are of same size's if not then first `resize` both images and then perform operation , you need to perform `resize` operation on java end rather than on `jni` side . Resultant image should be of size of input image but second image size should also be of input image size , all images size matter's in this case.